# Flow error when passing props to function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, static-typing

I have defined the following flow types:

```
/* @flow */

type PropsA = {|
  name: string,
  lastName: string,
|};

type PropsB = {|    
  email: string,
|};

type PropsC = {|
  text: string,
  phone: string,
  address: string,
|};

type ComponentAType = {|
    ...PropsA,
    type: 'componentA',
|};

type ComponentBType = {|
    ...PropsB,
    type: 'componentB',
|};

type ComponentCType = {|
    ...PropsC,
    type: 'componentC',
|};

type ComponentType =
  | ComponentAType
  | ComponentBType
  | ComponentCType;

const ComponentA = (props: PropsA) => {}
const ComponentB = (props: PropsB) => {}
const ComponentC = (props: PropsC) => {}

function testFunction(component: ComponentType) {
  const {type, ...props} = component;
  switch (component.type) {
    case 'componentA':
      return ComponentA(props);
    case 'componentB':
      return ComponentB(props);
    case 'componentC':
      return ComponentC(props);
    default:
      return null;
    }
}
```

However, i'm getting a lot of flow errors when passing props to a component/function saying that
`Cannot call 'ComponentA' with 'props' bound to 'props' because property 'email' is missing in 'PropsA' [1] but exists in rest of object pattern [2]. [prop-missing]`  even though email is not defined in `type PropsA` (same with other components). I'm not really sure why is flow complaining.

[Here is the full list of errors](https://flow.org/try/#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-F5ZsZfxDQ0QRr6K0fQ76KsJPiZqaKJozOn3rpWOQEO0qjEwGm-RgZqtc3iqnICGTWWteHjWFkMLViGxHYDKIGfGra5Ye+Q+9XAZ8h9MR3gxxOp0bZxR593e-DV0jfIPh2BR+PJ1mgQfyEfpkuV23KRvNzfd-fSo-n5YaR4FAHC1DA4RXt+k5sGBMALqwuqaEAA)

Answer (score 0):

Below is how to fix the errors. You have to type refine the object before you spread it and use components. Because `component` and `props` are different object references

[try flow](https://flow.org/try/#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-F5ZsZfxDQ0QRr6NJyAh2lUYmA036MDNVrm8VU5AQyay1vw89Nqj6HfRVhJ8TNTRRNGZ0+9dK2wFkMLViGxHYDKIGfGqR5ZddNa+R60PAZ9m3i25KO12e33yAO6JukUvpuPJ9Osx95xRF3iV5Y1xvy74mwxd2B7QxDzcx6nr+5aXpY15TjOSK+A+5BPtML7VHW8LnhSX4tq2f6dp43aAYSwGoRgYGsBBt7lqUsHwcueJpHgUAcLUMDhD+pHsIxMBgbqmhAA)